# Heroku deploy fails

Tags: java, heroku

I'm using Play framework with Java 1.7.

Last time deploy:

> -----> Play! app detected
>
> -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.7... done
>
> -----> Building Play! application...

This time deploy:

> -----> Play! app detected
>   /app/tmp/buildpacks/85dfc1d8f48aec0b42f03a59461dc516a918eb099c9e908767a7f42ddf326e12e48c6030ff4891e5c63f08e3b760ea09dee5bbfa4ca293b152d266406bfa29b3/bin/compile:
>   line 31: detect_java_version: command not found
>
> -----> Installing OpenJDK .../app/tmp/buildpacks/85dfc1d8f48aec0b42f03a59461dc516a918eb099c9e908767a7f42ddf326e12e48c6030ff4891e5c63f08e3b760ea09dee5bbfa4ca293b152d266406bfa29b3/bin/compile:
>   line 34: jdk_overlay: command not found
>
> -----> Building Play! application...

So after error log

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option UseSplitVerifier;
>   support was removed in 8.0
>     CompilerOracle: exclude jregex/Pretokenizer.next
>     Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8000
>     08:52:08,455 INFO  ~ Starting /tmp/build_bedf10ee7c8222565973235fe2454700
>     08:52:10,049 INFO  ~ Precompiling ...
>     08:53:02,606 ERROR ~
>
> @7e83895fc
>     Cannot start in PROD mode with errors
>
> Oops: UnexpectedException
>     An unexpected error occured caused by exception UnexpectedException: While applying class
>   play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer on
>   controllers.Application
>
> play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying play.CorePlugin@aecb35a on controllers.Application
>         at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:556)
>         at play.classloading.ApplicationClasses$ApplicationClass.enhance(ApplicationClasses.java:235)
>         at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadApplicationClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:167)
>         at play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.getAllClasses(ApplicationClassloader.java:431)
>         at play.Play.preCompile(Play.java:600)
>         at play.Play.init(Play.java:304)
>         at play.server.Server.main(Server.java:162)
>     Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: While applying class play.classloading.enhancers.LocalvariablesNamesEnhancer
>   on controllers.Application
>         at play.CorePlugin.enhance(CorePlugin.java:302)
>         at play.plugins.PluginCollection.enhance(PluginCollection.java:551)
>         ... 6 more
>     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
>         at javassist.CtClassType.getClassFile2(CtClassType.java:203)
>         at javassist.CtClassType.subtypeOf(CtClassType.java:303)
>         at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$TypeName.update(TypeData.java:274)
>         at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$TypeName.setType(TypeData.java:203)
>         at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData.setType(TypeData.java:46)
>         at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.Tracer.doInvokeIntfMethod(Tracer.java:828)
>         at ja
>   -----> Play! app detected

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you read the error log before pasting it here? It's very clear on the cause of your deploy failure.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please note that [Heroku no longer supports Play 1.x](https://help.heroku.com/PUIO7C8X/play-1-x-is-deprecated-with-support-ending-june-1-2017). If you can, please consider upgrading your application to Play 2.x, [which is still supported](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-support).

However, the issue you describe [has now been fixed](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common/pull/117). A dependency of the now deprecated Play 1.x buildpack broke backwards compatibility. Redeploying your application should work without any work from your side.